# How can I build an offline Webapp with Flet with no javascript knowledge?

Tags: python, caching, web-applications, offline, flet

I used "flet publish" command and successfully deployed a Webapp. Unfortunately, I didn't find a caching option command. I  already looked into the ".js" files generated earlier. I don't have Javascript knowledge, so it is hard to tweak that. Is there a way to do this in Python code with Flet?